# $x\in \mathbb{R} : P(x) \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow Q(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $P(x)-Q(x)=c \in \mathbb{Z}$ or...

Tags: polynomials

$P(x),Q(x)$ are two polynomials such that $x\in \mathbb{R} : P(x) \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow Q(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $P(x)-Q(x)=c$  or  $P(x)+Q(x)=d, $ where  $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ must be of degrees $\geq 1$ otherwise if we take two constant polynomials with non integer values the condition will be satisfied and the the result will not be true

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are two polynomials of degree greater than $1$.

Then there is some $a$ such that $P(a),Q(a)\in\mathbb Z$, and $P$ and $Q$ are both strictly monotone on $[a,+\infty)$

Suppose that they are both increasing. Otherwise, multiply the decreasing ones by $-1$.

We will now prove that $P-Q$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$

Let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence for the points on $[a,\infty)$ where $P$ attains a value in $\mathbb Z$, and $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence for the points on $[a,\infty)$ where $Q$ attains a value in $\mathbb Z$.

First, here are some interesting properties about $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Clearly, $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$

$(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ goes to $\infty$, so $[a,\infty)=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}[u_n,u_{n+1})$

$$P(u_{n+1})=P(u_n)+1$$

$$Q(v_{n+1})=P(v_n)+1$$

These two give us $$P(u_{n+1})-Q(u_{n+1}) = P(u_{n})-Q(u_{n})$$

So $P(u_{n})-Q(u_{n})$ is constant. We'll call it $c$.

---

Let $x\in [a,\infty)$, then $x\in[u_p,u_{p+1})$, for some $p\in \mathbb N$.
$$\begin{align}
P(u_p)  \leq  P(x)  \leq P(u_{p+1})& =P(u_p)+1 \\
Q(u_p) \leq   Q(x)  \leq Q(u_{p+1})& = Q(u_p)+1
\end{align}$$

So now we have:
$$\begin{align}
P(u_p)-Q(u_p)-1 &\leq P(x)-Q(x) \leq P(u_p)-Q(u_p)+1 \\
c-1 &\leq P(x)-Q(x) \leq c+1
\end{align}$$

So $P-Q$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$

Therefore, $P-Q$ is constant, and this constant is in $\mathbb Z$, since $(P-Q)(a)\in Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true; Define:
$P(x)=1/3$,  and
$Q(x)=1/5$ .
then
$P(x) \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $Q(x) \notin \mathbb{Z}$ but $P(x)-Q(x)=\cdots$ and $P(x)+Q(x)=\cdots$

Comment: @Winther!  it says :"**if** P(x) is integer then Q(x) is integer". so this **is** a valid counter-example. see [*Truth table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for $p → q$

Comment: My fault, I misread. Yes, it is indeed a valid function.